# Retrieve all record and insert to another table form another db

Tags: php, mysql

I have troubles about php & mysql. I've to retrieve all records from DB1's table and then I have to insert them again to DB2's table.

```
<?php
require_once 'includes/config.php';
include 'includes/header.php';
if(isset($_POST['go'])){        
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT id,username,password FROM $db_database1.account")
        or die(mysql_error());

    echo "Record ".mysql_num_rows($query)." retrieve";

    while($result_row = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
        $account_ID = $result_row['id'];
        $username = $result_row['username'];
        $password = $result_row['password'];
        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO $db_database2.account(uid,username,password) VALUES('$account_ID','$username','$password')")
            or die(mysql_error());
        $selectId = mysql_insert_id();
    }
}
mysql_close($conn);
?>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="content">
<form method="post" action="<?PHP $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
<input type="submit" name="go" value="Go" />
</form>
</div>
<?php include 'includes/footer.php';?>
```

According to this code just one record was inserted. How can I insert all retrieved records?

Comment: -1 for asking **not the actual question** you really need an answer for.

Answer (score 1):

To insert records into another table you need one single query, run from mysql console without PHP:

```
INSERT INTO db_database2.account SELECT id,username,password FROM db_database1.account
```

Notes on your code

- you have to escape strings you are adding to the query
- for some reason you are inserting into the same database
- asking for the mysql_insert_id() makes no sense as you are apparently inserting a_i id already
- there is no use for storing second mysql_query result into variable
- yet this variable gets overwritten <- here is the reason your code runs once.
- there is no use for echoing `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` here. just leave form action blank.
- yet you are actually leaving form action blank as you just forgot to `echo` this variable
- I see no use for all the form and HTML here. Can't you just run this code without forms?

as it seems that whole mess is just to hash passwords, you need no extra tables then
just simple

```
UPDATE account SET password = md5(concat(id,username,password));
```

always have a database backup before such manipulations

Comment: It's query won't work in my program coz of i hv to insert hash password to db_database.account that's why i'm using with php :D

Comment: you can hash password in the same query as well.

Comment: you don't even need another table for this. you can hash your passes in the same table

Comment: pass hash method is custom i think it's can't use with mysql query

Comment: oh, you are using custom hash of extreme security. pretty wise decision. will make your site defense impenetrable.

Comment: It's not my custom hashing. I'm just integrating to my requirement. Now it's solve it's coz of 2 $query variable :D